# How to only allow one input element in a form to be entered based on radio button input

Tags: html

I've found people wanting to just submit one piece of data however I can't find a post about only allowing one input.

I am looking to only allowing the ID OR Month OR Date to be searched. I attempted a Radio Button here but it still accepts other values and sends them to the PHP file which outputs all the values. For example, if the month February is chosen and ID 20 then ID 20 and all of February is outputted.

How do you allow only one of the inputs or still continue to use the radio button?

Here is my HTML code:

```
<form action="searchProjections.php" method="get" class="center">
        <input class="w3-radio" type="radio" name="SearchChoice" value="IDSearch" checked>
        <label class="w3-validate">Search for ID</label><br>
        <input class="w3-radio" type="radio" name="SearchChoice" value="MonthSearch">
        <label class="w3-validate">Search for Month</label><br>
        <input class="w3-radio" type="radio" name="SearchChoice" value="DateSearch">
        <label class="w3-validate">Search for Date</label><br>
        <label>ID</label>
        <input class="w3-input w3-border-0" type="text" name="IDsend" maxlength="2">
        <label>Month</label>
        <select name="monthSend" class="w3-select">
            <option value="" selected>Search Month</option>
            <option value="January">January</option>
            <option value="February">February</option>
            <option value="March">March</option>
            <option value="April">April</option>
            <option value="May">May</option>
            <option value="June">June</option>
            <option value="July">July</option>
            <option value="August">August</option>
            <option value="September">September</option>
            <option value="October">October</option>
            <option value="Novemebr">Novemeber</option>
            <option value="December">December</option>
        </select>
        <label>Date</label>
        <input class="w3-input w3-border-0" type="text" name="DateSend" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" pattern="[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}" title="Enter a date in this formart YYYY-MM-DD" min="2017-02-01">
        <br>
        <input class="w3-button w3-hover-light-green w3-black w3-padding-large" type="submit"> 
        <input class="w3-button w3-hover-light-green w3-black w3-padding-large" type="reset">
    </form>
```

Comment: Reword your question? If you want one field to be sent by clicking the submit button, you'll need separate submit buttons or a lot of JS

Comment: @SamirChahine I have reworded it, sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here I propose an HTML+CSS based solution:

Code a single form for each search field, with its own submit+reset buttons, and use the radio buttons to display just one form at time.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Forms selector</title>
<style type="text/css">

#tabcontainer1 {
    clear: left;
    width: 40%;
    height: 7em;
    border: solid 1px;
    overflow: auto;
}

label.tabbutton {
    clear: left;
}

#tabcontainer1 .tab {
    display: none;
}
input#tabbutton1:checked ~ #tabcontainer1 #tab1,
input#tabbutton2:checked ~ #tabcontainer1 #tab2,
input#tabbutton3:checked ~ #tabcontainer1 #tab3 {
    display: block;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Forms selector</h1>

<input type="radio" name="tabbutton" id="tabbutton1" class="tabbutton" value="1" checked="checked"/><label for="tabbutton1" >search by id</label>
<input type="radio" name="tabbutton" id="tabbutton2" class="tabbutton" value="2"/><label for="tabbutton2" >search by month</label>
<input type="radio" name="tabbutton" id="tabbutton3" class="tabbutton" value="3"/><label for="tabbutton3" >search by date</label>

<div id="tabcontainer1">
    <div id="tab1" class="tab">
        <form>
            <h3>Search for id</h3>
            <label>ID</label>
            <input class="w3-input w3-border-0" type="text" name="IDsend" maxlength="2">
            <div>
                <input class="w3-button w3-hover-light-green w3-black w3-padding-large" type="submit">
                <input class="w3-button w3-hover-light-green w3-black w3-padding-large" type="reset">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="tab2" class="tab">
        <form>
            <h3>Search for month</h3>
            <label>Month</label>
            <select name="monthSend" class="w3-select">
                <option value="" selected>Search Month</option>
                <option value="January">January</option>
                <option value="February">February</option>
                <option value="March">March</option>
                <option value="April">April</option>
                <option value="May">May</option>
                <option value="June">June</option>
                <option value="July">July</option>
                <option value="August">August</option>
                <option value="September">September</option>
                <option value="October">October</option>
                <option value="Novemebr">Novemeber</option>
                <option value="December">December</option>
            </select>
            <div>
                <input class="w3-button w3-hover-light-green w3-black w3-padding-large" type="submit">
                <input class="w3-button w3-hover-light-green w3-black w3-padding-large" type="reset">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div id="tab3" class="tab">
        <form>
            <h3>Search for date</h3>
            <label>Date</label>
            <input class="w3-input w3-border-0" type="text" name="DateSend" placeholder="YYYY-MM-DD" pattern="[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}" title="Enter a date in this formart YYYY-MM-DD" min="2017-02-01">
            <div>
                <input class="w3-button w3-hover-light-green w3-black w3-padding-large" type="submit">
                <input class="w3-button w3-hover-light-green w3-black w3-padding-large" type="reset">
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can intercept the form submission in js.

jQuery:

```
$.fn.check_errors = function() {
    var _el = $(this);
    $(this).submit(function( event ) {
        // TEST YOUR INPUTS HERE

        if(){  // good to submit
            return;
        }

        // handle the error
        event.preventDefault();

    });
};
```

Use it:

```
$('#form_id').check_errors();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a php / html / js monster, but ins't it possible (via php? or js?) to make it so that when you choose an option, only the corresponding category choices are enabled, then disable the others inputs?

For example let's say you choose IDSearch by clicking on the related radio btn :
 - disable `<select name="monthSend"... >...</select>`
 - disable `<input name="DateSend" .../>`
 - leave ONLY `<input name="IDsend" .../>` enabled